Python/Tkinter Not always refreshing canvas
I am moving an app from Pygame to TkInter - with moderate success, but I am having an issue I don't understand.  I have included the two most pertinent functions (I hope - if someone needs more, I can provide it).  The issues is that the screen doesn't always update after I rebuild the canvas (at the end of the show routine.  By adding a Trace (just issues a logger.debug), it works but if I don't call Trace, it doesn't always update.  --init-- is called once, show is called once for each image to be displayed.  Is there a call I need to force an update?  fwiw, the platform is a Raspberry Pi, running their latest Ubuntu clone.  All OS and apps are current.
    def __init__(self, width, height, font="helvetica", font_size=50, full_screen=True, caption=False,
             display_delay=45):

    self.font = (font, font_size)
    self.caption = caption
    self.display_delay = display_delay
    self.last_display = -99
    self.file_path = None
    self.image = None
    self.size = (0, 0)
    self.text = None
    self.root = tk.Tk()

    # Establish the screen attributes and size
    if full_screen:
        # self.root.attributes("-zoomed", True)
        self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
    else:
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.root.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

    self.root.configure(cursor=None)
    self.root.focus_set()
    self.root.title(f"Photo Slideshow v{version}")
    self.root.configure(bg="black")
    self.text_base = self.height - int(self.font[1] * 0.38)

    # Build a canvas covering the entire screen
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg="black")
    self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    logger.debug(f"Display initialized; size=({self.width}x{self.height}, font={self.font}, "
                 f"delay={self.display_delay}")

def show(self, file, index, nfiles):
    self.canvas.delete("all")
    #TODO: Enclose image/caption processing in try/except block - skip if error
    Trace(f"File={file}")
    self.file_path = file
    p = Path(file)
    if not p.is_file():
        logger.info(f"Note: image {file} no longer exists - skipped")
        return
    pp = PurePath(file)
    self.text = pp.parent.name
    try:
        Trace(f"BaseDir={self.text}")
        img = Image.open(file)
        self.size = img.size
        cap = IPTCInfo(file)["caption/abstract"]
        if cap is not None and self.caption:
            self.text += ": " + cap.decode("utf-8")
        scale = trunc(min(self.width / self.size[0], self.height / self.size[1]), 3)
        scaled_image = ImageOps.scale(img, scale)
        scaled_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(scaled_image)
        logger.debug(f"Displaying: {file}, size={self.size}, cap={cap}")
        sprite = self.canvas.create_image(self.width / 2, self.height / 2, anchor="center", image=scaled_image)
        textbox = self.canvas.create_text((10, self.text_base), text=self.text, fill="white", font=self.font,
                                          anchor="sw")
        box_dim = self.canvas.bbox(textbox)
        box_dim = box_dim[:3] + (self.height,)
        Trace(f"{box_dim}")
        bbox = self.canvas.create_rectangle(box_dim, fill="black")
        mem = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
        countbox = self.canvas.create_text((10, 10), text=f"{index:,d} of {nfiles:,d}; mem={mem}%, ip={local_ip}", fill="white",
                                      font=(self.font[0], 20), anchor="nw")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info(f"Error {e} processing {file} - skipped")
        return
    self.canvas.tag_lower(bbox, textbox)
    self.last_display = now()
    Trace(sprite)


It is better to provide code on how show() is called, i.e. a [mre].
